# Trouble making a price calculator to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that should be working, but when i put it in the code module (divi theme, wordpress) it doesnt work. When I put it in a notepad it works, but not in the website. (http://elodash.com/tabela/)

```html
<html hola_ext_inject="disabled"><head></head><body screen_capture_injected="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true"><center>
 
 
 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function EloEvolution(attrs) {
  var image_path = 'http://elodash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/';
  this._products = {
    b5: {
      id: 2854,
      price: 0,
      image: image_path + 'bronze_5.png'
    },
    b4: {
      id: 2854,
      price: 20,
      image: image_path + 'bronze_4.png'
    },
    b3: {
      id: 2854,
      price: 20,
      image: image_path + 'bronze_3.png'
    },
    b2: {
      id: 2854,
      price: 20,
      image: image_path + 'bronze_2.png'
    },
    b1: {
      id: 2854,
      price: 20,
      image: image_path + 'bronze_1.png'
    },
    s5: {
      id: 2855,
      price: 22,
      image: image_path + 'silver_5.png'
    },
    s4: {
      id: 2855,
      price: 22,
      image: image_path + 'silver_4.png'
    },
    s3: {
      id: 2855,
      price: 22,
      image: image_path + 'silver_3.png'
    },
    s2: {
      id: 2855,
      price: 22,
      image: image_path + 'silver_2.png'
    },
    s1: {
      id: 2855,
      price: 22,
      image: image_path + 'silver_1.png'
    },
    g5: {
      id: 2856,
      price: 28,
      image: image_path + 'gold_5.png'
    },
    g4: {
      id: 2856,
      price: 28,
      image: image_path + 'gold_4.png'
    },
    g3: {
      id: 2856,
      price: 28,
      image: image_path + 'gold_3.png'
    },
    g2: {
      id: 2856,
      price: 28,
      image: image_path + 'gold_2.png'
    },
    g1: {
      id: 2856,
      price: 28,
      image: image_path + 'gold_1.png'
    },
    p5: {
      id: 2857,
      price: 35,
      image: image_path + 'platinum_5.png'
    },
    p4: {
      id: 2857,
      price: 35,
      image: image_path + 'platinum_4.png'
    },
    p3: {
      id: 2857,
      price: 35,
      image: image_path + 'platinum_3.png'
    },
    p2: {
      id: 2857,
      price: 35,
      image: image_path + 'platinum_2.png'
    },
    p1: {
      id: 2857,
      price: 52,
      image: image_path + 'platinum_1.png'
    },
    d5: {
      id: 2858,
      price: 80,
      image: image_path + 'diamond_5.png'
    },
    d4: {
      id: 2858,
      price: 80,
      image: image_path + 'diamond_4.png'
    },
    d3: {
      id: 2858,
      price: 80,
      image: image_path + 'diamond_3.png'
    },
    d2: {
      id: 2858,
      price: 80,
      image: image_path + 'diamond_2.png'
    },
    d1: {
      id: 2858,
      price: 80,
      image: image_path + 'diamond_1.png'
    },
    c5: {
      id: 2896,
      price: 250,
      image: image_path + 'challenger_1-2.png'
    },
    c4: {
      id: 0,
      price: 0,
      image: image_path + 'challenger_1-2.png'
    },
    c3: {
      id: 0,
      price: 0,
      image: image_path + 'challenger_1-2.png'
    },
    c2: {
      id: 0,
      price: 0,
      image: image_path + 'challenger_1-2.png'
    },
    c1: {
      id: 0,
      price: 0,
      image: image_path + 'challenger_1-2.png'
    }
  };
 
  this.currencyFormat = 'R$';
  this.currencyDecimalSeparator = ',';
 
  this._errorMessages = {
    dest_lt_cur: "Nível Desejado é menor que o Atual"
  }
  this._sequence = [
    'b5','b4', 'b3', 'b2', 'b1',
    's5','s4', 's3', 's2', 's1',
    'g5','g4', 'g3', 'g2', 'g1',
    'p5','p4', 'p3', 'p2', 'p1',
    'd5','d4', 'd3', 'd2', 'd1',
    'c5','c4', 'c3', 'c2', 'c1'
  ];
  this.errors = [];
 
 
// ============== PUBLIC METHODS ================
 
  // Need to set these settings
  // this.selectCurrentTier = attrs['selectCurrentTier'];
  // this.selectCurrentDivision = attrs['selectCurrentDivision'];
  // this.currentWrapImage = attrs['currentWrapImage'];
  // this.selectDestinationTier = attrs['selectDestinationTier'];
  // this.selectDestinationDivision = attrs['selectDestinationDivision'];
  // this.destinationWrapImage = attrs['destinationWrapImage'];
  // this.priceContainer = attrs['priceContainer'];
  // this.addToCartButton = attrs['addToCartButton'];
  // this.addToCartUrl = attrs['addToCartUrl'];
 
  this.settings = function(attrs) {
    for (var key in attrs) {
      this[key] = attrs[key];
    }
    this._attachAddToCart();
 
    return this;
  }
 
  this.change = function() {
    this.ck = $(this.selectCurrentTier).val() + $(this.selectCurrentDivision).val();
    this.dk = $(this.selectDestinationTier).val() + $(this.selectDestinationDivision).val();
    this.current = this._products[this.ck];
    this.destination = this._products[this.dk];
 
    this.updateImage();
    var price = this.sumValue();
    $(this.priceContainer).text(this._formatCurrency(price));
    return this;
  }
 
  this.updateImage = function() {
    $(this.currentWrapImage).css('background-image', 'url(' + this.current.image + ')');
    $(this.destinationWrapImage).css('background-image', 'url(' + this.destination.image + ')');
 
    if($(this.selectDestinationTier).val() == 'c') {
        $(this.selectDestinationDivision).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $(this.selectDestinationDivision).removeAttr('disabled');
                }
  }
 
  this.sumValue = function() {
    this._getSequence();
    if(this.i_dest < this.i_cur) {
      this._addError('dest_gt_cur');
      return false;
    }
 
    var sum = 0;
    this._execInSequence(function(p, k){
      sum += p.price;
    });
    return sum;
  }
 
  this.addToCart = function() {
    var evo = this;
    if(evo.beforeAddToCart) evo.beforeAddToCart();
    evo._getSequence();
 
    var products = [];
    evo._execInSequence(function(p){
      products.push(p);
    });
 
    function ajaxOrRedirectToCart(_products) {
      var p = products.shift();
      if(!p){
        window.parent.location = evo.cartUrl;
      }
      var url = evo.addToCartUrl.replace('%product_id', p.id);
      jQuery.get(url).success(function(){
        ajaxOrRedirectToCart(_products);
      });
    }
 
    ajaxOrRedirectToCart(products);
  }
 
  this.errorMessages = function () {
    var trErrors = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.errors.length; i++) {
      var k = this.errors[i];
      if(this._errorMessages[k]) {
        trErrors.push(this._errorMessages[k]);
      } else {
        trErrors.push(k);
      }
      return trErrors;
    }
  }
 
// ============== PRIVATE METHODS ================
  this._getSequence = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this._sequence.length; i++) {
      if(this.ck === this._sequence[i]) {
        this.i_cur = i;
      }
      if(this.dk === this._sequence[i]) {
        this.i_dest = i;
      }
    }
  }
 
  this._execInSequence = function(func) {
    for(var i = this.i_cur + 1; i <= this.i_dest; i++) {
      var p_key = this._sequence[i];
      var product = this._products[p_key];
      func(product, p_key);
    }
  }
 
  this._formatCurrency = function(val) {
    var o = [];
    var decPart = new String(parseInt((val - parseInt(val)) * Math.pow(10, this._currencyDecimalQty)) || 0);
    var intPart = new String(parseInt(val) || 0);
    if (decPart < 10) {
      decPart = "0" + decPart;
    }
 
    o.push(this.currencyFormat);
    o.push(' ')
    o.push(intPart);
 
    o.push(this.currencyDecimalSeparator);
    o.push(decPart);
 
    return o.join('');
  }
 
  this._attachAddToCart = function() {
    var evo = this;
    jQuery(evo.addToCartButton).click(function(){
      evo.addToCart();
    });
  }
 
  this._addError = function(err) {
    this.errors.push(err);
  }
 
  this.init = function(attrs) {
    if(attrs) {
      this.settings(attrs);
    }
  }
  this.init(attrs);
}
 
$(function(){
  var evo = new EloEvolution({
    selectCurrentTier: '#ct',
    selectCurrentDivision: '#cd',
    selectDestinationTier: '#dt',
    selectDestinationDivision: '#dd',
    currentWrapImage: '#cti',
    destinationWrapImage: '#dti',
    priceContainer: '#price',
    addToCartButton: '#cart',
    addToCartUrl: '/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=%product_id',
    cartUrl: '/carrinho',
    beforeAddToCart: function() {
      jQuery('#loader').show();
    }
  }).change();
  $('#ct,#cd,#dt,#dd').change(function(){
    // we need to call inside an anonymous function
    // because we use `this`, inside evo.change function,
    // referring to evo instance, instead the dom object
    // that was changed.
    evo.change();
  });
});
</script>
 
<style>
 
* {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
 
#content2 {
  width:725px;
  background:url('http://elodash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/bg_calc.png') no-repeat center top;
  height:410px;
  background-size: 100%;
}
 
.current_tier_img,
.desired_tier_img {
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  background-image: url(http://elodash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/bronze_5.png);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 70px;
  margin-left: -96px;
}
 
#wrapper {position: relative;}
 
.desired_tier_img {
  margin-left:-94px;
}
 
.desired_division {
  background:#FFF;
}
 
.current_tier_img span,
.desired_tier_img span,
#loader, h2 {display: none;}
 
br {clear:both;}
 
/*
#loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 300px;
}*/
 
.current_tier_division,
.desired_tier_division {
  width:49%;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position: relative;
}
 
#price {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left:50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet Ms';
  color:#FFF;
  margin-left:-50px;
  top: 170px;
  font-size: 18px;
 
}
 
#cart {
  width: 150px;
  height:72px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0px;
  background:url(http://elodash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/bt_comprar.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  top: 220px;
 
}
 
#cart:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background:url(http://elodash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/bt_comprar2.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
 
.current_tier,
.desired_tier {
  background:#FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-left: -65px;
  width: 130px;
}
 
.current_tier select,
.desired_tier select {
  border:0px;
  background: none;
  height: 28px;
}
 
.current_tier select:first-child
.desired_tier select:first-child {
  width:100px;
}
 
.current_tier select:last-child,
.desired_tier select:last-child {
  float:right;
}
 
/*#price {
float: right;
padding: 5px 10px;
width: 83px;
text-align: right;
border: 1px dotted #d1d1d1;
background: #f1f1f1;
margin-right: 159px;}*/
 
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/style.css"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/js/page_context.js"></script>
 
<div id="loader">Adicionando produto no carrinho...<br>Obs: O tempo de espera depende da quantidade que for adicionado ao carrinho.<br><img src="http://elojob.com.br/calculadora/ajax-loading.gif"></div>
<div id="content2">
  <div id="main_content">
   
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="current_tier_division">
        <div id="cti" class="current_tier_img" style="background-image: url(http://elojob.com.br/calculadora/tier/silver_1.png);"><span>Posição Atual</span></div>
        <div class="current_tier">
          <select id="ct">
            <option value="b">Bronze</option>
            <option value="s" selected="">Prata</option>
            <option value="g">Ouro</option>
            <option value="p">Platina</option>
            <option value="d">Diamante</option>
          </select>
          <select id="cd">
            <option>5</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option selected="">1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="desired_tier_division">
        <div id="dti" class="desired_tier_img" style="background-image: url(http://elojob.com.br/calculadora/tier/gold_5.png);"><span>Posição Desejada</span></div>
        <div class="desired_tier">
          <select id="dt">
            <option value="b">Bronze</option>
            <option value="s">Prata</option>
            <option value="g" selected="">Ouro</option>
            <option value="p">Platina</option>
            <option value="d">Diamante</option>
                              <option value="c">Mestre</option>
          </select>
          <select id="dd">
            <option selected="selected">5</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="sv" class="server" style="display:none;">
        <select>
          <option>Brazil</option>
        </select>      
      </div>
      <div class="vpn" style="display:none;">
        <input name="VPN Protection" type="checkbox" value="VPN Protection" id="vpn_id">
      </div>
      <br>
      <h2> VALOR </h2>
      <div id="price">R$ 35,00</div>
      <div>
        <button id="cart"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
</center></body></html>
</body>
</html>
```

So, it works in the snippet, but [here](http://elodash.com/tabela/) it does not.

Comment: the java tag should be a javascript tag ...

Comment: EloJob é proibido cara

Comment: Your Javascript contains br-tags.. why?

Comment: Why are there br-tags on literally every line... what are you doing?

Comment: I ctrl+c, ctrl+v this code from here: http://pastebin.com/9fC7CsSF, i don't really know.

Comment: the br-tags are messing up the code?

Comment: Yes.... If you want to learn how to make websites, don't go and copy paste something without knowing what it is. Learn HTML and Javascript, so you actually know what you are doing. This is making me so uncomfortable. Honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the page you linked... Okay.. It's clear that you copy pasted the entire freaking website. Like literally everything.

Start off by removing the unnecessary HTML tags. This includes ALL the `<br />` tags inside your Javascript code. `<br />` is HTML and does not belong in the Javascript code. Removing unnecessary tags also means removing the entire `<head>` portion of the second page you pasted in. You do not want to have multiple body- and head-tags on your page.

Once that is done, it should work just like your snippet code on this page does.

But really, go learn HTML, CSS, and Javascript. It will benefit you so much, because clearly you have no clue what you are doing.

1) HTML & CSS - https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web
2) Javascript - https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help and the tips.

Answer (score 1):

if I view the source of your webpage, I see this:

```
<p><meta charset="utf-8"><br />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><br />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><br />
<script type="text/javascript"><br />
function EloEvolution(attrs) {<br />
  var image_path = 'http://elodash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/';<br />
  this._products = {<br />
    b5: {<br />
      id: 2854,<br />
      price: 0,<br />
```

that is not valid JavaScript; you are copying and pasting it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, i have zero knowledge of javascript, how can I do it right?